# $A \cdot B = A \cdot C$ does not imply that $B = C$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to prove the following:

> If $A,B,C$ are non-zero vectors such that $A \cdot B = A \cdot C$, then it's not necessarily true that $B = C$.

*My proposed proof.*

> Suppose $A \cdot B = 0$.  Multiply $A \cdot B = 0$ by $x \in \mathbb R$, $x \neq 1$, so that $x(A \cdot B) = 0$. Then $A \cdot xB = 0$. Let $C = xB$.  Thus, it's not always true that $B = C$ if  $A \cdot B = A \cdot C$.

Does that work?

Comment: Looks good. You could also be explicit that $xB \ne B$.

Comment: A little warning: Using capital letters for vectors is going to lead to confusion later when you encounter matrices and linear maps. It's better to use `\vec{a}` ($\vec a$) or `\mathbf{a}` ($\mathbf a$) or some other decoration (underline, italic bold, whatever) that distinguishes vectors from scalars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is enough to notice that every pair of orthogonal (perpendicular) vectors has dot product equal to zero.

To illustrate the point take 3 vectors:
$$
    a = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\qquad b = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix} \qquad c = \begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix}
$$
It's easy to see that $a\cdot b = a\cdot c = 0$, but $b\neq c$.

Comment: What I would call a "Proof by Counter Example".

Comment: I think it is the best kind of proof. Clear and simple. ;)